# How to block WebView in Android from converting 'https' to 'http'?

Tags: android

My WebView converts `https` to `http`, as evident from checking the `url` parameter in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method. 
I have tried using

`webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE)`, but it doesn't work.

How do I fix this?
Please help!

Comment: Show us some of the code you are using. Make the smallest reproduceable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: can you provide the code?

Answer (score 2):

you can handle every url as you wish just set up your webview via customized WebViewClient

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
                if (url.startWith("https")) {                     
                    //do whatever you need
                    }
                    return false;
                }else if(....
```